# Select2 ajax processing results

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using select2 with ajax searhc queries to DB. Everything is working just fine but I have 1 little problem.

Lets say I am looking through IDs in database and When I start writing to select2 ID: 111 - record is found - 1 row but I have there 2 rows with the 111 on the top which I wrote.

Here is javascript:

```
$(".select2-ajax").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            tags: [],
            ajax: {
                url: "ajax/" + uri,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        q: term.term
                    }
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

Screen of result:

[image]

Expected result:

The same as on the image but without the 1st option where is only 111

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was caused by `tags: []`

```
$(".select2-ajax").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: {
                url: "ajax/" + uri,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                quietMillis: 50,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });
```